# Resource 7bed8adc-9ed9-49dc-b15e-6660e2fc3285 transitioned to failure state ERROR when use openstacksdk to create_server

Tags: openstack

When I create the openstack server, I get bellow Exception:

> Resource 7bed8adc-9ed9-49dc-b15e-6660e2fc3285 transitioned to failure state ERROR

My code is bellow:

```
server_args = {
    "name":server_name,
    "image_id":image_id,
    "flavor_id":flavor_id,
    "networks":[{"uuid":network.id}],
    "admin_password": admin_password,
}

try:
    server = user_conn.conn.compute.create_server(**server_args)
    server = user_conn.conn.compute.wait_for_server(server)
except Exception as e:  # there I except the Exception
    raise e
```

When create_server, my `server_args` data is bellow:

```
{'flavor_id': 'd4424892-4165-494e-bedc-71dc97a73202', 'networks': [{'uuid': 'da4e3433-2b21-42bb-befa-6e1e26808a99'}], 'admin_password': '123456', 'name': '133456', 'image_id': '60f4005e-5daf-4aef-a018-4c6b2ff06b40'}
```

My openstacksdk version is `0.9.18`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I find the `flavor` data is too big for openstack compute node, so I changed it to a small flavor, so I create success.